# Apache Airflow : Dag task marked zombie, with background process running on remote server

Tags: airflow

**Apache Airflow version:**1.10.9-composer

**Kubernetes Version :** Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.12-gke.6002", GitCommit:"035184604aff4de66f7db7fddadb8e7be76b6717", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-01T23:13:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

**Environment:** Airflow, running on top of Kubernetes - Linux version 4.19.112

- **OS :** Linux version 4.19.112+ (builder@7fc5cdead624) (Chromium OS 9.0_pre361749_p20190714-r4 clang version 9.0.0 (/var/cache/chromeos-cache/distfiles/host/egit-src/llvm-project c11de5eada2decd0a495ea02676b6f4838cd54fb) (based on LLVM 9.0.0svn)) #1 SMP Fri Sep 4 12:00:04 PDT 2020
- **Kernel :** Linux gke-europe-west2-asset-c-default-pool-dc35e2f2-0vgz
  4.19.112+ #1 SMP Fri Sep 4 12:00:04 PDT 2020 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

**What happened ?**
A running task is marked as Zombie after the execution time crossed the latest heartbeat + 5 minutes.
The task is running in background in another application server, triggered using SSHOperator.

```
    [2021-01-18 11:53:37,491] {taskinstance.py:888} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): load_trds_option_composite_file> on 2021-01-17T11:40:00+00:00
    [2021-01-18 11:53:37,495] {base_task_runner.py:131} INFO - Running on host: airflow-worker-6f6fd78665-lm98m
    [2021-01-18 11:53:37,495] {base_task_runner.py:132} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'dsp_etrade_process_trds_option_composite_0530', 'load_trds_option_composite_file', '2021-01-17T11:40:00+00:00', '--job_id', '282759', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dsp_etrade_trds_option_composite_0530.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpge4_nva0']
```

**Task Executing time:**

```
dag_id      dsp_etrade_process_trds_option_composite_0530
duration    7270.47
start_date  2021-01-18 11:53:37,491
end_date    2021-01-18 13:54:47.799728+00:00
```

**Scheduler Logs during that time:**

```
[2021-01-18 13:54:54,432] {taskinstance.py:1135} ERROR - <TaskInstance: dsp_etrade_process_etrd.push_run_date 2021-01-18 13:30:00+00:00 [running]> detected as zombie
{
textPayload: "[2021-01-18 13:54:54,432] {taskinstance.py:1135} ERROR - <TaskInstance: dsp_etrade_process_etrd.push_run_date 2021-01-18 13:30:00+00:00 [running]> detected as zombie"
insertId: "1ca8zyfg3zvma66"
resource: {
type: "cloud_composer_environment"
labels: {3}
}
timestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:54.432862699Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/asset-control-composer-prod/logs/airflow-scheduler"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:55.714437665Z"
}
```

**Airflow-webserver log :**

```
X.X.X.X - - [18/Jan/2021:13:54:39 +0000] "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
{
textPayload: "172.17.0.5 - - [18/Jan/2021:13:54:39 +0000] "GET /_ah/health HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "-" "GoogleHC/1.0"
"
insertId: "1sne0gqg43o95n3"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:45.401670481Z"
logName: "projects/asset-control-composer-prod/logs/airflow-webserver"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:50.598807514Z"
}
```

**Airflow Info logs :**

```
2021-01-18 08:54:47.799 EST
{
textPayload: "NoneType: None
"
insertId: "1ne3hqgg47yzrpf"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:47.799661030Z"
severity: "INFO"
logName: "projects/asset-control-composer-prod/logs/airflow-scheduler"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:50.914461159Z"
}

[2021-01-18 13:54:47,800] {taskinstance.py:1192} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=dsp_etrade_process_trds_option_composite_0530, task_id=load_trds_option_composite_file, execution_date=20210117T114000, start_date=20210118T115337, end_date=20210118T135447
Copy link
{
textPayload: "[2021-01-18 13:54:47,800] {taskinstance.py:1192} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=dsp_etrade_process_trds_option_composite_0530, task_id=load_trds_option_composite_file, execution_date=20210117T114000, start_date=20210118T115337, end_date=20210118T135447"
insertId: "1ne3hqgg47yzrpg"
resource: {2}
timestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:47.800605248Z"
severity: "INFO"
logName: "projects/asset-control-composer-prod/logs/airflow-scheduler"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-18T13:54:50.914461159Z"
}
```

**Airflow Database shows the latest heartbeat as:**

```
select state, latest_heartbeat from job where id=282759
--------------------------------------
state   | latest_heartbeat
running | 2021-01-18 13:48:41.891934
```

**Airflow Configurations:**

```
celery
worker_concurrency=6

scheduler
scheduler_health_check_threshold=60
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold=300
max_threads=2

core
dag_concurrency=6

Kubernetes Cluster :
Worker nodes : 6
```

**What was expected to happen ?**

- The backend process takes around 2hrs 30 minutes to finish. During
  such long running jobs the task is detected as zombie. Eventhough the
  worker node is still processing the task. The state of the job is
  still marked as 'running'. State if the task is not known during the
  run time.

Comment: Hello Team,

Debugging further, I have noticed a pattern where the worker is not sending heartbeat to db. When the time difference between the scheduler current time & latest heart is more than 5 minutes + X seconds, the task is detected as zombie.

Comment: Did you discover what led to the worker not sending the heartbeat?

Comment: @Corey , the worker logs didn't give much information why the heartbeat is not sent.

Comment: We had a similar issue but we were able to determine (from the cluster monitoring tools) that it was actually a memory limitation issue. Reconfiguring the cluster to use highmem worker nodes fixed our issue.